# In HashiCorp Vault Dynamic Secret GCP Auth Method Refresh Trigger failed attampt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vault

I am using HashiCorp Vault Database Dynamic Secret feature. The problem is
Refresh Trigger failed attempt deletes the dynamic secret from the database after the default TTL expires. So to prevent dynamic secret deletion I overridden the method as below.
Will this work else please suggest the correction

```
@Bean
@Override
public SessionManager sessionManager() {
ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication = clientAuthentication();
Assert.notNull(clientAuthentication, "ClientAuthentication must not be null");
int refreshBeforeExpiry = 3600; // Overrides default
LifecycleAwareSessionManagerSupport.FixedTimeoutRefreshTrigger refreshTrigger = new LifecycleAwareSessionManagerSupport.FixedTimeoutRefreshTrigger(
        refreshBeforeExpiry, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
LifecycleAwareSessionManager lifecycleAwareSessionManager =  new LifecycleAwareSessionManager(clientAuthentication, getVaultThreadPoolTaskScheduler(), restOperations(), refreshTrigger);
lifecycleAwareSessionManager.setLeaseStrategy(LeaseStrategy.retainOnError()); 
return lifecycleAwareSessionManager;
}
```